# Returning variables from a prepared statement function PHP

Tags: php, mysql, function, prepared-statement

I have multiple pages on a website that require the same data from a table. So instead of writing out an sql statement on each page I want to write a function.

Here is my function:

```
function getInfo($u_id) {

    global $conn;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT report.*, users.* FROM report INNER JOIN users ON report.report_user_id=users.user_id WHERE report_user_id = ? ORDER BY report_id DESC LIMIT 5") or die ('Problem Preparing Query');
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $u_id);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        //reports
        $report_user_id     = $row['report_user_id'];   
        $rep_date           = $row['rep_date'];
        $rep_location       = $row['rep_location'];
        $rep_notes          = $row['rep_notes'];

        //users 
        $user_id            = $row['user_id'];
        $username           = $row['username'];
        $fname              = $row['user_firstname'];  
        $lname              = $row['user_lastname'];
        $user_email         = $row['user_email'];
        $user_image         = $row['user_image'];
        $user_number        = $row['user_number']; 
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

The function works, in that it fetches the data from the table but I don't know how to output the variables. Any example I have seen using prepared statements in functions are for inserting data into a table rather than fetching data.

I have tried binding the results, creating an array, returning each variable but in every case I have errors or can only return the first variable.

The function as is does not throw up any errors on its own but further down my webpage when I try to use one of the fetched variables it tells me that it is undefined.

```
 $u_id = 1;
 getInfo($u_id);

<a class="text-inherit" href="profile/index.html"><?php echo $fname .' '. $lname; ?></a>


Notice: Undefined variable: fname in....
```

So my question is, how can I get the variables that have been fetched in this function?

Comment: You want a table? Make one, and put each pass of the loop in a `<tr></tr>` with each separate result in your loop in `<td></td>`.

Comment: I don't want a table the variables are to be used on a profile page setting. The function is located in another file (functions.php) from where the variables are to be called.

Comment: Your `function getInfo($u_id)` doesn't `return` or `echo` anything, and since your `$fname`/`$lname` are only in scope inside the function you can't access them. Save your data to an array, and the return the array. Then you can loop over the function result.

Comment: Multiple issues. Looks like you want 5 results? You want them all? Are you expecting a single row result? If that was the case you could `return $result->fetch_object();`, never making the loop at all. Then you will have an object result from `$res = getInfo($u_id);` then use `$res->user_firstname;` and `$res->user_lastname;`.

Comment: @PHPglue Wow! Thanks. I've spent a good three hours trying various things and searching google for a solution and this works perfectly. Much less work as well. Can you highlight comments as answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a single row result solution:

```
function getInfo($u_id){
  global $conn;
  $stmt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM report INNER JOIN users ON report.report_user_id=users.user_id WHERE report.report_user_id=$u_id ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1") || die ('Problem Preparing Query');
  if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
    return $stmt->fetch_object();
  }
  else{
    // no results were found
  }
  return false;
}
$obj = getInfo($u_id);
if($obj){
  echo "<a class='text-inherit' href='profile/index.html'>{$obj->user_firstname} {$obj->user_lastname}</a>";
}
```

Comment: you are declaring $conn as global variable and immediately going on to query. where are you making the connection to database here?

Answer (score 1):

```
function getInfo($u_id) {
    global $conn;

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT report.*, users.* FROM report INNER JOIN users ON report.report_user_id=users.user_id WHERE report_user_id = ? ORDER BY report_id DESC LIMIT 5") or die ('Problem Preparing Query');
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $u_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = [];
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    $stmt->close();   
    return $rows;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's not working since `$fname` and `$lname` are local variables in that function and when the function returns they are gone.

Put all of them inside an array and either return them or put them inside `$GLOBAL`.